# How to add " ' " in command awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sh

how to add on the output from the file using awk as below:

Like:

```
cat /tmp/lista_table_vertical.txt  | awk '{print "major_compact " $1}'
major_compact game_activities
major_compact interatividade_activities
major_compact testeCompression
major_compact testeCompression2
major_compact testeSlowQuery
major_compact users_algorithms
major_compact users_algorithms2
```

I want insert the "'" at the begin and at the end.
for example:

```
major_compact 'game_activities'
major_compact 'interatividade_activities'
major_compact 'testeCompression'
major_compact 'testeCompression2'
major_compact 'testeSlowQuery'
major_compact 'users_algorithms'
major_compact 'users_algorithms2'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to use ascii representation:

```
\047
```

check

```
man ascii
```

Finally:

```
awk '{print "major_compact \047" $1 "\047"}' /tmp/lista_table_vertical.txt
```

Another (maybe hard to remember & to read) solution :

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "major_compact '\''" $1 "'\''"}' /tmp/lista_table_vertical.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
awk -v sq="'" '{print "major_compact " sq $1 sq}' /tmp/lista_table_vertical.txt
```

i.e. pass single quote as a variable to awk and use it anywhere using var name.

**PS:** You don't need to use unnecessary `cat` also.

Comment: For me this is a better solution than using the `\047`, since here you do not need to remember the number of the single quote.

Comment: @Jotne - No, `\047` is better because you can simply use it anywhere you want a single quote, e.g. inside regexp constants. You can write `/\047foo\047/` but you can't write `/sqfoosq/`, nor can you always write `$0 ~ sq "foo" sq` because then you need to do additional handling of `"foo"` as a computed regexp instead of a regexp constant (e.g. need to double-escape meta-characters). It just gets unnecessarily clumsy in some contexts so best just always use `\047`.

Comment: @jotne: You can also use `'\''` which is the same number of keystrokes as `\047` without forcing you to remember the code.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to do this more than once, the simplest thing is to create a file such as `script.awk` that contains:

```
{ printf "major_compact '%s'\n", $1 }
```

And then run

```
awk -f script.awk /tmp/lista_table_vertical.txt
```

Doing this avoids all the messiness of escaping quotes on the shell command line.  If you're only going to have to type it once, then one of the one-liners in other answers will work OK for you (but this may be easier to get right the first time, even so — and if you have to get it right, you had to type it, in some shape or form, more than once).